# How to buffer pixels by their associated pixel values?

Tags: matlab, raster

What methods can I use to buffer pixels by their associated pixel values?  For example, the image on the left shows a raster image with pixel radius values ranging from 0 - 5 (note "black" values are 0).  The image on the right shows the buffers I am trying to produce based on these pixel values.  Per Stack Exchange policies, I have also included a MATLAB script for reproducible data.

[image]

---

```
% Generate a grid of 0s to begin with.
m = zeros(300, 400, 'uint8');

% Generate 1000 random pixels.
numRandom = 1000;
linearIndices = randi(numel(m), 1, numRandom);

% Assign a radius value of 1-5 for each pixel
m(linearIndices) = randi(5, [numel(linearIndices) 1]);

% Display it.  
image(m);
colormap(hot);
```

Comment: Edit: nvm, the use of the word buffer here is not clear.

Comment: @Ashish Your use of "buffers" in the solution you provided is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
% Generate a grid of 0's to begin with.
m = zeros(300, 400, 'uint8');

% Generate 1000 random pixels.
numRandom = 9;
linearIndices = randi(numel(m), 1, numRandom);

% Assign a radius value of 1-5 for each pixel
m(linearIndices) = randi(5, [numel(linearIndices) 1]);



%%
buffer = false(size(m));
for radius =1:5 % update to actual range
    im_r  = m==radius;
    se    = strel('disk',radius);
    im_rb = imfilter(im_r, double(se.getnhood()));

    buffer = buffer | im_rb;
end

imshowpair(m,buffer,'montage');
```

Comment: Many thanks @Ashish.  This is a creative and simple solution.